# How do I get rid of the flickering of text output in console?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I'm using Win32 API. This is just a very simple rendering of a rectangle. There are two screen buffers which I just swap alternately to display every next frame. Every time I run the program, I see horizontal flickers. I haven't tried this on any other device so I'm not really sure if you will be able see it too but if you do then perhaps you can show me some ways to get rid of it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE create_screen_buffer(SHORT height, SHORT width);

int main(void)
{
  enum { SCREENS = 2 }; /* number of screen buffers */
  HANDLE screen[SCREENS]; /* console screen buffers */
  HANDLE next_screen;
  int screen_index = 0;;
  COORD screen_origin = { 0, 0 }; /* top-left corner of screen */
  DWORD chars_written; /* used in `WriteConsole()` */
  int i, j, row; /* loop counters */

  enum { MAP_HEIGHT = 30, MAP_WIDTH = 70 };
  /* this is where you prepare stuff before rendering to the screen */
  char map[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH];

  /* initialize screen buffers */
  for (i = 0; i < SCREENS; ++i)
  {
    screen[i] = create_screen_buffer(MAP_HEIGHT, MAP_WIDTH);

    if (screen[i] == NULL)
    {
      printf("ERROR: Failed to load screen buffers.\n");

      /* free any previously loaded screen buffers */
      for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        CloseHandle(screen[j]);
    }
  }

  /* initialize map */
  for (i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; ++i)
    memset(map[i], '*', MAP_WIDTH);

  for (i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
  {
    next_screen = screen[screen_index];

    /* start writing from the top-left corner */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(next_screen, screen_origin);

    /* write the map to the next frame */
    for (row = 0; row < MAP_HEIGHT; ++row)
    {
      WriteConsoleA(next_screen, map[row], MAP_WIDTH, &chars_written, NULL);
      WriteConsoleA(next_screen, "\n", 1, &chars_written, NULL);
    }

    /* display the next frame */
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(next_screen);

    /* set the next screen */
    screen_index ^= 1;

    /* just a little delay for more steady framerate */
    Sleep(1);
  }

  /* free all screen buffers */
  for (i = 0; i < SCREENS; ++i)
    CloseHandle(screen[i]);

  /* (optional) show the standard output */
  SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));

  return 0;
}

HANDLE create_screen_buffer(SHORT height, SHORT width)
{
  HANDLE screen;
  COORD size;
  CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;

  screen = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       /* read/write access */
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, /* shared */
    NULL,                               /* default security attributes */
    CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,            /* must be TEXTMODE */
    NULL                                /* reserved, must be NULL */
    );

  if (screen == NULL)
    return NULL;

  size.X = width + 1;
  size.Y = height + 1;
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(screen, size);

  /* hide the text cursor */
  GetConsoleCursorInfo(screen, &cci);
  cci.bVisible = FALSE;
  SetConsoleCursorInfo(screen, &cci);

  return screen;
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  As a sanity test, I tried setting one of the screen handles to NULL, and noticed the last line would flicker if I did that.  It looked almost as if it was being scrolled.  Try changing your loop so that it doesn't write a newline character on the very last line and see if that helps.  _i.e._ only write the newline when `row < MAP_HEIGHT - 1`.  You might consider not writing newlines ever, and instead just rely on cursor positioning.

Comment: @[paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy): I already tried writing just a single row without any newline. A single row. It still flickers. The way I understand it is that no one is supposed to see the writing process since the buffer being written to in every iteration is not shown on the console screen until `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer()` is called. I don't think this is a CPU issue since the spikes are below 50%. Perhaps it's an API thing.